# How to disable user ineraction in stage in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, user-interaction

I am new in Action Script.

I need to disable user interaction in `stage` . How can I achieve this.

I have tried with

```
stage.mouseEnabled = false; and
stage.mouseChildren = false;
```

both getting crash,

```
Error: Error #2071:  The stage class does not implement this property or method.
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this:

```
mouseEnabled = false;
mouseChildren = false;
```

in the document class or at timeline.

Comment: I given in a button Click. it is not working. After change the status again clicks are working on the screen.

Comment: Leave `mouseEnabled = false;` and when user clicks on the stage MouseEvent will not be fired.

Answer (score 0):

Vinesh,

if you want to do that for objects added manually to timeline, then you will access it with keyword this. Try adding this to your timeline:

```
var arr:Array=new Array();

    for(var i:int=0; i<this.numChildren; i++)
    {

        arr.push(this.getChildAt(i));
        arr[i].mouseEnabled=false;
    }
```

and if you added objects with 
`stage.addChild(someObject)`, 
then you will use 
`stage.someObject.mouseEnabled=false;`